# Visual Studio Code global typings definitions

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there is any way to save global typings definitions for VS Code. I know you can add them to your project but I think it would be much cleaner if I could install these globally, so it wouldn't show up under my project. Also, it would make it much faster to start a new project if VS Code already knew all these definition without me having to add them every time I start.

I'm not looking for much, having definitions for Node, JQuery and Express would suffice for now.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not really think that local definitions are the problem. Sometimes you might get to the point when you do need to have different versions of the same definition files in different projects or do not want to have some of them due to the conflicts with systems ones in lib.d.ts. Therefore I believe local storage is a better choice.

I use it all the time and to overcome your issues I can recommend to do the following.

Add "files.exclude" to the .vscode/settings.json:

```
{
    "files.exclude": 
    {
        "typings": true
    }
}
```

This will hide all typings so you do not see them in project.

To start project from scratch fast you can have a tsd.json with commonly used definitions. For example:

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts": {
      "commit": "5a8fc5ee71701431e4fdbb80c506e3c13f85a9ff"
    },
    "jasmine/jasmine.d.ts": {
      "commit": "5a8fc5ee71701431e4fdbb80c506e3c13f85a9ff"
    }
  }
}
```

And correspondingly in your package.json add postinstall action like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "tsd update --save --overwrite"
  }
}
```

After that all you have to do to initialize definitions for the new project is to run

```
npm install
```

This will fetch all definitions and you will not see them in the IDE.

Hope this will help.